# Add array tag into JSON string value using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, .net

I got a JSON string value :

```
{"refKey":"1","recordType":"address","bureauType":"consumer","controlData":{"success":"true"},"candidateRecordScores":[{"bestScore":"7","inputRecordScores":"7"}]}
```

I want to change `candidateRecordScores` node inside inputRecordScores value as array format.

Below output format i need:

```
"inputRecordScores":[7]
```

Also **candidateRecordScores** child element value changed as string format to INT

Below Final output i need:

```
{"refKey":"1","recordType":"address","bureauType":"consumer","controlData":{"success":"true"},"candidateRecordScores":[{"bestScore":7,"inputRecordScores":[7]}]}
```

This is my code look like this:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

using System;

using System.IO;

using System.Net;


amespace CAAS_SoftCIR

{

    public class Class1

    {
        static void Main(string[] args)

        {
            string strJson = @"{

                                  'ExpressMatch': {

                                    'refKey': '1',

                                    'recordType': 'address',

                                    'bureauType': 'consumer',

                                    'controlData': {

                                      'success': 'true'

                                    },

                                    'candidateRecordScores': [

                                      {

                                        'bestScore': '7',

                                        'inputRecordScores': '7'

                                      }

                                    ]

                                  }

                                }";


            JObject rss = JObject.Parse(strJson);

            //var rssTitle = Convert.ToString(rss["ExpressMatch"]);

            var rssTitle = (object)rss["ExpressMatch"];

            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject((object)rss["ExpressMatch"] , Formatting.None);

            Console.WriteLine(jsonNew);

        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Please show your attempt. It seems like you haven't tried anything yet.

Comment: Please refer my code above This is my code look like this:@Llama

Comment: I've seen your code above, but aside from parsing the JSON to a `JObject` (a good first step), nothing seems to relate to the task you're posting about. What has stopped you from looping through the items in `candidateRecordScores`, taking the value of `inputRecordScores` and then replacing the property value with an array of that value?

Comment: Yes you are correct Current output [{"bestScore":"7","inputRecordScores":"7"}] look like a string format i need array format [{"bestScore":"7","inputRecordScores":[7]}] @Llama

Comment: Then surely you can just loop through `candidateRecordScores` and update the `inputRecordScores` property of each item by overwriting it with a new value?

Comment: can you write a code. it's very helpful for me. candidateRecordScores multiple array value @Llama

Comment: Some time return multiple list "candidateRecordScores":[{"bestScore":"7","inputRecordScores":"7"},{"bestScore":"10","inputRecordScores":"10"}]} like this @Llama

Comment: That's why you use a loop...

Comment: Can you modify my code @Llama

Comment: Pseudocode: `foreach (JObject childObj in rss["ExpressMatch"]["candidateRecordScores"]) { currentValue = childObj["inputRecordScores"]; int parsedValue = int.Parse(currentValue); childObj["inputRecordScores"] = new JArray() { parsedValue }; }`

Comment: Hi @Llama, can you add your code to the answer as the concept had tested and it works well. Thanks. [Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wtGPeD)

Answer (score 4):

try it in Main method

```cs
string strJson = @"{
    'ExpressMatch': {
    'refKey': '1',
    'recordType': 'address',
    'bureauType': 'consumer',
    'controlData': {
        'success': 'true'
    },
    'candidateRecordScores': [
        {
            'bestScore': '7',
            'inputRecordScores': '7'
        }
    ]
    }
}";


JObject rss = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(strJson);

foreach(JObject score in rss["ExpressMatch"]["candidateRecordScores"]) {
    score["inputRecordScores"] = new JArray((int)score["inputRecordScores"]);
}

var newJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rss, Formatting.Indented);

Console.WriteLine(newJson);
```

Comment: Thank you @Henry Tran. Some tag is added extra like EXpressMatch Parent Node